# How do while loops help in checking conditions anywhere in the loop?

Tags: python, while-loop

Can anyone explain the paragraph associated with the following code below, to me .

```
while True:
  line = input(">")
  if line == "done":
    break
  print(line)

print("Done!")
```

This way of writing `while` loops is common because you can check the condition anywhere in the loop (not just at the top) and you can express the stop condition affirmatively (“stop when this happens”) rather than negatively (“keep going until that happens”).

Comment: This is common use case of while loop in any programming languages.By using while True you create an infinite loop and you can terminate the loop from inside the loop if something happens, like here if user inputs done we terminate the process or this is not the case then go on.This is pattern of using while true loop is very comman.

Comment: while True:
  line = input(">")
  if line == "done":
      print(f'line: {line}')
  else:
     print("Done!")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before each iteration of a loop the software checks if the condition is true or not. (Writing while True is the same as while(1) and will always run until a stop condition is established.

The paragraph you quoted states that you can decide when to exit the loop instead of having the software exit when the condition is false (in the while loop above, it will never happen).

This allows for more code control.

For example, say your code was:

```
While (my_var == 1):
 line = input(">")
 if line == "done":
    my_var = 0
 print(line)

print("Done!")
```

The software will exit the code only on the NEXT iteration(because my_var no longer equals 1), thus wasting time and resources.

Comment: I got syntax error While (my_var == 1):

Comment: my_var needs to be declared beforehand (ex. my_var =1)

Comment: Thank you so much, I have understood the concept well. :)